# Same category from different lists

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I originally had a Dataframe like

```
datax = {'col1' : [['apple','pear','peach'],['kiwi','pear','apple','watermelon']]}
db = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1'], data = datax))
```

Every rows of the column 'col1' is a list of strings and every element of the string should be a category.
What I'm trying to do is to create a category object that contains all the categories from the different rows and then I would like to apply the categorical transformation to each row.
I managed to create a dictionary that contains all the words from the different rows in this way:

```
categ = []
for lst in db['col1']:
    for term in lst:
        if term not in categ:
            categ.append(term)
categ = pd.Series(categ, dtype = 'category')
```

But I think that this is not a Pythonic way to reach the goal.
Furthermore, I don't know how to repalce the strings inside the rows ( that are also the values in my dictionary ) with their keys.

Is there a better way to extract and map the categories?

Basically, what I need to do is this:

```
>>db['col1']
   [['apple','pear','peach'],
   ['kiwi','pear','apple','watermelon']]
```

And what I want to reach is:

```
>>db['col1']
   [[0,1,2],
   [3,1,0,4]]
```

Note that I'm trying to use a dictionary beacuse I want the possibility to reverse the operation and recreate the original column.
I have way more than 2 rows, so I can't enumerate all the possible cases.

Comment: @anky_91 it's fantastic.The only problem is that if there are categories with more than one word separated by white space, the algorythm won't work, and this could be my case. Anyway this is what I was looking for, I can easily adapt this code to my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so you can use , explanation is added as comments:

```
import itertools
a=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(db.col1)) #flatten the lists
d=dict(zip(a,pd.factorize(a)[0])) #create a dictionary mapping

#output->{'apple': 0, 'pear': 1, 'peach': 2, 'kiwi': 3, 'watermelon': 4}
#next line replaces the value of list with value of dictionary d

db.col1.apply(lambda x: [sum(int(d[k]) for k in y.split()) for y in x])
```

***Output***

```
0       [0, 1, 2]
1    [3, 1, 0, 4]
```